# There is an extra space in using cmder in win10

Tags: conemu, cmder

when I upgrade my os to win10, the cmder always have an extra space on the beginning line before the cursor, whether using bash or cmd etc. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuRU3.png)

and I have tried some method from google, all of them didn't work well for me, just like, add command in the cmder start environment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjpUF.png)

or changed the lamber to other character.

Is there anyone has the other solutions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you have old ConEmu build. Cmder version is about nothing interesting

Comment: @Maximus sorry for missing the cmder version, the cmder version the newest for now : 1.3.11.843. and I found the sulotion below in the answers, thanks all the same.

Comment: I've asked about ConEmu version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I have found a solution for it :
go control panel -> Clock and Region -> region -> Administrative card -> change system local -> un choose the :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kXOj.png)

it worked fine for me ^_^

PS : my os win10  version : 1809  cmder version : Version 1.3.11.843